# Trying to reverse engineer the formula for combined chance

Tags: calculus

I want to reverse engineer "1-((1-x)^y)=z" so that instead of using x and y to find z, I can use y and z to find x. Google doesn't cough up answers to that quite so easily; I tried Googling "1-((1-x)^y)=z" to no avail, and it was sheer luck that I found the base formula for combined chance simply by Googling "combined chance" in the first place.

I'm not a math person, but rather someone who wants to create an item drop rate in a game that works out such that while players should almost never have to test their sanity by grinding for the item that they want for any extended period of time, their limited inventory typically doesn't get flooded with items as they defeat enemies either. (As I am not a math person, I apologize if I'm using any incorrect terminology in this question).

Let's say that there are 20 enemies that hold a certain item in a stage, and I want the chance of the player obtaining at least one of those items after 2 runs of the stage to be 80%. I want to find "x" in "1-((1-x)^40)=0.8". How do I use "40" ("y") and "0.8" ("z") to find "x"?

I have no idea what tag(s) to apply to this, so please let me know if I'm using the wrong tag and what tag(s) I should be using if I am using the wrong tag. So far I changed the tag from "probability" to "calculus"; if there's any other tags I should have please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag should be calculus.

$z=1-(1-x)^y \Leftrightarrow 1-z=(1-x)^y\Leftrightarrow 1-(1-z)^{1/y}=x$

If $z<1$ and $y\neq0$, you can calculate $(1-z)^{1/y}$ using this formula : $(1-z)^{1/y}=exp(\frac{1}{y} ln(1-z))$

Comment: @GiovanniResta So, to use y and z to find x I want to use "1-(1-z)^(1/y)=x"? Therefore, the answer to my example question would be "1-(1-0.8)^(1/40)=~0.0394" x=~0.0394?

Comment: Yes, try to put that x back in the first formula and see if you get back to the z you had (0.8).

Answer (score 2):

$$1 - (1 - x)^y = z\quad \Rightarrow\quad (1-x)^y=1-z\quad\Rightarrow\quad y=\frac{\log(1-z)}{\log(1-x)}$$

$$(1-x)^y=1-z\quad\Rightarrow\quad 1-x=(1-z)^{1/y}\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=1-(1-z)^{1/y}$$